# DLookup When Trying Use Form Field as Criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I am new to Access and also to VB. I have a report that displays information on transformers, the report displays data from a query that queries data from two different tables. I would like to use a button to open a PDF document saved in one of the tables.

The code I have so far is this:

```
Private Sub Command70_Click()

    Dim hypa As String

    hypa = DLookup("[TestReport]", "TransformerPics", "TxID =  " & [Reports]![TransformerInfoSheet]!TXID)

    Application.FollowHyperlink [hypa]

End Sub
```

The error i get is `Run-time error '2471' The expression you have entered as a parameter produced this error: 'TP00686'`

TP00686 is the transformer number that is displayed on the report.

Comment: can you show your table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have some quotes in there:

```
hypa = DLookup("[TestReport]", "TransformerPics", "TxID =  '" & [Reports]![TransformerInfoSheet]!TXID & "'")
```

Please also see:

- [DLookup Usage Samples](http://access.mvps.org/access/general/gen0018.htm)
- [Dlookup using a string variable as criteria parameter](http://utteraccess.com/forum/Dlookup-string-variable-t1148626.html)

Comment: HI TJ, thank you for the quick response. I copied and pasted that line of code and it still gives me the same error. Is there anything else I could try.

Comment: Quotes is your problem.   Try this:

http://access.mvps.org/access/general/gen0018.htm

And this one might be key:

http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Dlookup-string-variable-t1148626.html